# Having hard time computing generalized forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

[image]Suppose we have a rigid body and point $O$ is fixed. It is clear then that it has three degrees of freedom and so we can choose Euler angles $\phi,\psi,\theta$ as generalized coordinates to describe its position.

But how to compute $Q_{\psi},Q_{\phi},Q_{\theta}$ -- generalized forces? Can you give any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The rotation matrix $~\mathbf R~$ is a function of the Euler angles $~\phi~,\theta~,\psi~$

from here you obtain the angular velocity

$$\mathbf \omega=\mathbf J_R(~\phi~,\theta~,\psi~)\,\mathbf{\dot{q}}$$

where $~\mathbf{\dot{q}}=[\dot\phi~,\dot\theta~,\dot\psi]^T~$ and $\mathbf J_R~$ $~3\times 3~$ distributor matrix

thus the generalized torque

$$\mathbf Q=  \mathbf J_R^T\,\mathbf \tau\\
\mathbf\tau=\mathbf r\times \mathbf F\\
\mathbf F=[F_1~,-F_2~,0]^T$$

Matrix $~\mathbf J_R~$

with
$$R=R_z(\psi)\,R_x(\phi)\,R_z(\theta)\quad \Rightarrow\\
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{3}}&\omega_{{2}}
\\ \omega_{{3}}&0&-\omega_{{1}}\\ 
-\omega_{{2}}&\omega_{{1}}&0\end {array} \right] 
=\mathbf R^T\,\frac{d}{dt}\,\mathbf R\quad \text{or}\quad
\mathbf\omega=\mathbf J_R\,\mathbf{\dot{q}}\\ 
J_R= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \theta \right) &0&\sin \left( 
\phi \right) \sin \left( \theta \right) \\ -\sin
 \left( \theta \right) &0&\sin \left( \phi \right) \cos \left( \theta
 \right) \\  0&1&\cos \left( \phi \right) 
\end {array} \right] 
$$

---

Comment: Why $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{J}_{R}^{T}\tau$? Is there a formula you used to derive this? Or maybe it is related to virtual work?

Comment: Yes is related to virtual work

Comment: How does $\mathbf{J}_{R}$ matrix exactly look? Could you provide a link? Thanks.

Comment: I add your request  see edit

Comment: Is there a physical (or maybe intuitive) explanation of why $J_{R}$ is independent of $\psi$?

Comment: for different rotation matrices you obtain different $~J_R$ matrices

Comment: No, I am still not sure if we need to express $r$ in terms of angles, and how..?

Comment: r is body fixed and also the force

Comment: But this point is moving or it does not matter as long as it is fixed on body?

Comment: It dose not matter the body is moving because the torque

Comment: And the last question, I suppose: could you please derive the formula for Q, using virtual work? Because I tried and got something different

Comment: The problem is: I can't see where $J$ matrix comes from when deriving $Q$...

Comment: see again my edit to your question

Comment: No, I got that; I mean, how you derive $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{J}^{T}\tau$ using virtual work?

Comment: This is the theory, you have to eliminate the “constraint torques”

Comment: Does this fact have a long derivation?

Comment: Btw, I created a question regarding this equality