# Why $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{J}_{R}^{T}\tau$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, lagrangian-formalism

Yesterday I asked this question: [Having hard time computing generalized forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682487/having-hard-time-computing-generalized-forces)

And I got the answer, however I don't get why $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{J}_{R}^{T}\tau$, namely I don't see where matrix $\mathbf{J}$ comes from. Could anyone elaborate? How to get this expression using virtual work?

Comment: To keep the notation consistent , note that generalized forces are scalar, so no boldface on $Q$ and cartesian torque is vector so boldface for $\boldsymbol \tau$.

Comment: Q is a vector of generalized forces, so that's why I made it bold

Comment: I was thinking of this expression for each joint. As a system if $Q$ is a vector of gen. forces, then $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ is a vector of vectors and it needs to be boldfaced also.

Comment: This is a valid question and it shouldn't have been closed. Just because _some_ people don't understand the question does not mean it lacks details.

Comment: Consider supplying the relevant details in this post rather than just a link. If anything happens to the other post this one becomes very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this example
[image]

\begin{align*}
&\text{Newton equations of motion (free body diagram)}\\
&I_1\dot{\omega}_1=\tau_1+\tau_c\\
&I_1\dot{\omega}_1=-\tau_c\\
&\text{and the constraint equation}\\
&\omega_1-\omega_2=0
\end{align*}
or with matrix notation
\begin{align*}
  &\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    I_1 & 0 \\
    0 & I_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf I}\,
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\omega}_1 \\
    \dot{\omega}_2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{\dot{\omega}}}=
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    \tau_1 \\
    0 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf \tau}+
  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf c}\tau_c\tag 1
\end{align*}

from the constraint equation you choose the generalized coordinate $~\omega_1~\quad\Rightarrow\omega_2=\omega_1~$ thus
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{{\omega}}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
                         1 \\
                         1 \\
                       \end{bmatrix}}_{\mathbf{J}_R}\omega_1\quad,
    &\mathbf{{\dot \omega}}={\begin{bmatrix}
                         1 \\
                         1 \\
                       \end{bmatrix}}\dot \omega_1
\end{align*}

to eliminate the constraint torque $\tau_c~$ you multiply equation (1) with $~\mathbf{J}_R^T~$ (with$~\mathbf{J}_R^T\,\mathbf c=\mathbf 0~$ ) you obtain the equation of motion

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{J}_R^T\,\mathbf{I}\,\mathbf{J}_R\,\dot\omega_1=\mathbf{J}_R^T\,\mathbf{\tau}
 \end{align*}

so $~\mathbf Q=\mathbf{J}_R^T\,\mathbf{\tau}~$ are the generalized "forces".

Comment: Is there more direct approach, like just computing $Q_{q_{i}=}\sum\limits_{j}^{n}\left(F_{j},\dfrac{\partial r_{j}}{\partial q_{i}}\right)$ to implement it in my problem? If you think that no, then thx anyways

Comment: analog you obtain   \begin{align*}
& Q_i= \sum_j\tau_j\,\underbrace{\frac{\partial \omega_i(q,\dot{q})}{\partial \dot{q}_j} }_{J_R(i,j)}
 \end{align*}

Comment: Oh, this formula really helps! That is another way to derive the desired result, thanks! Did you find this formula somewhere or got on your own?

Comment: I found the following formula on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics): $Q = \mathbf{F}\cdot \dfrac{\partial \mathbf{V}}{\partial\dot{q}}+\mathbf{T}\cdot\dfrac{\partial \vec{\omega}}{\partial\dot{q}}$. How does the first term vanish?

Comment: The equations of motion contains translation Newton and rotation Euler equations the constraint forces at the joint must be eliminated

Comment: I suppose that first term vanishes because the speed of point $O$ in my case is actually $0$...

Answer (score 1):

This expression comes from the balance of power across a joint.

Keeping in the rotational theme (although there is generalization to screw joints that include  both revolute and prismatic), the kinematic relationship across the joint is

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm out} = \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm in} + \mathbf{J}_R \dot{q} \tag{1}$$

Now the power balance relationship is expressed with the following scalar equation

$$ P_{\rm out} = P_{\rm in} + P_{\rm motor} \tag{2} $$

where $$\begin{aligned}
 P_{\rm motor} & = \dot{q} \, Q \\
 P_{\rm in} &= \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm in}^\top \boldsymbol{\tau} \\ 
 P_{\rm out} &= \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm out}^\top \boldsymbol{\tau}
\end{aligned}$$

or

$$ 
\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm out}^\top \boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm in}^\top \boldsymbol{\tau} + \dot{q} \,Q \tag{3} $$

Now use (1) in (3) to get

$$ \dot{q}\,Q = ( (\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm in}+ \mathbf{J}_R \dot{q} )^\top \boldsymbol{\tau} - \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm in}^\top \boldsymbol{\tau}) = \dot{q}\, (\mathbf{J}_R^\top \boldsymbol{\tau})$$

or

$$ \boxed{ Q = \mathbf{J}_R^\top \boldsymbol{\tau} } \tag{4} $$

Comment: Is the first component of $Q$ in your case $Q_{\varphi}$?

Comment: $Q$ is the generalized force for the joint, and if it is a revolute joint you can call it $Q_\varphi$ although the notation isn't common. Each author makes up their own notation.